# How to measure statistical significance in retention cohorts

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test

The number of registered users 1 group= 5873, the number of returned in 1 day=1887. The number of registered users 1 group= 6520, the number of returned in 1 day=1794.

Is it possible to say with confidence that the retention of group 1 is higher than the 2? What statistical test can be used to prove this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is a "registered user"?  What is the process for not returning?  We need some more detail.

Comment: @DemetriPananos "registered user" - This is the user who installed the app.. " not returning" - This means that the user did not log into the application the next day after installation.